# filter pipe by object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I got simple Pipe to filter values in my table:

```
transform(value: any, term: any) {
    if (!term) return value;
    console.log('term: '+term+' value '+value)
    return value.filter((item: any) => {
        for (let prop in item) {
            if (typeof item[prop] === "string" && item[prop].indexOf(term) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

And there is my html

```
 <tbody>
                      <tr
                        *ngFor="let file of fileUploads | FilterPipe: name |async | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10,
                        currentPage: p }; let i = index">
                        <td id="lPart" style="cursor: pointer;font-weight: normal;">
                           <a href="http://localhost:8080/api/file/{{file.name}}{{file.ext}}">{{file.name}}</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

in my .ts

```
this.fileUploads = this.uploadService.getFiles();
```

this.fileUploads is a Observable

```
fileUploads: Observable<any[]>;
```

typeof is a Object

I got error

> core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: items.filter is not a function
> at FilterPipe.transform (FilterPipe.ts:20)

How my pipe should looks like to filter through objects?

-Edit

This is what I am sending from my backend

```
Server is running on port 8080.
[
  { name: 'image', ext: '.jpg' },
  { name: 'rodo', ext: '.pdf' },
  { name: 'test', ext: '.xlsx' }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the object using `Object.keys()` which returns an array of keys in the object. And then get the object using the following code:

```
transform(value: any, term: any) {
  if (!term) return value;
  console.log('term: '+term+' value '+value)
  return  Object.keys(value).filter((itemValue: any) => {
    const item = value[itemValue];
    for (let prop in item) {
      if (typeof item[prop] === "string" && item[prop].indexOf(term) > -1) {
        return item;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: I got error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Then when I want type another letter in input is error: core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of null

Comment: Ok I solved this error but this transform return one one row as expected but without name, why?

Comment: Instead to returning a boolean true you can return whole item. I think this will resolve your problem.